# Ionic 2: Allow tabbing through inputs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I cannot seem to find a way to change any keyboard behavior in my app.  I have tried to use the ionic-native Keyboard plugin, but nothing seems to change.

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

export class NewRepositioningModal {
    constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) {

    // I've tried true as well
    this.keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
}
```

but I never see any bar, and the only button on the keyboard says "Go".  I'm trying to enable tabbing between inputs and can't even get the "Next" button to show.